# Showing/Hiding <div> Based on <li>.hover()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a menu that would display via `.slideDown()` a `<div id="menuDiv">` based on which ID specified `<li>` of `<div id="menuDiv">`'s `<ul>` the cursor is under. Additionally, the `<div id="menuDiv">` should `.slideUp()` when the cursor goes out of `<div id="menuContainer">` except when the cursor goes down over the `<div id="menuDiv">` itself.

I have this markup:

```
   <div id="menuContainer">
   <!-- this is styled to be your standard CSS <ul> menu (<ul>'s list-style: none; <li> float: right) -->
        <ul>
            <li id="overSlide1"><a href="#1" class="linkClass">Alpha</a></li>
            <li id="overSlide2"><a href="#2" class="linkClass">Beta</a></li>
            <li id="overSlide3"><a href="#3" class="linkClass">Gamma</a></li>
            <li id="overSlide4"><a href="#4" class="linkClass">Theta</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="menuDiv">
    <!-- This is position right under the <div id="menuContainer"> via CSS -->
    </div>
```

and did this for the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#overSlide1").hover(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideDown(250, function(){
        });
    }, function(){

    });

    $("#overSlide2").hover(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideUp(250, function(){
        });
    }, function(){

    });

    $("#overSlide3").hover(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideDown(250, function(){
        });
    }, function(){

    });

    $("#menuDiv").hover(function(){

    }, function(){
        $(this).slideUp(75);
    });
});
```

I'm having problems with "except when the cursor goes down over the `<div id="menuDiv">` itself".

Comment: "cursor goes down" part of my idea ???

Comment: jQuery menus have been done **so. many. times.** Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Matt: I'm so sorry I'm not as informed as you sir. I shouldn't have asked then. -.-

Comment: I'm just sayin', are [13,300,300 results](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+menu) not enough for you?

Comment: @Erick Garcia don't be sorry. not everyone knows everything. however, put some effort in finding out online.

Comment: I guess I'm just lost my focus on actually just getting it done. I found my logical mistake in my code. I should've just made the <div id="menuDiv"> part of the <li> so that the <div> is still under the <li>. Anyway, thanks for the comments. (I think this should be closed now.)

Comment: @Erick Garcia if you know the answer, just leave it in the answer section and after 2 days you can accept your it as an answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#overSlide1").mouseover(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideDown(250, function(){
        });
    };

    $("#overSlide1").mouseout(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideUp(250, function(){
        });
    };
 $("#overSlide2").mouseover(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideDown(250, function(){
        });
    };

    $("#overSlide2").mouseout(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideUp(250, function(){
        });
    };

 $("#overSlide3").mouseover(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideDown(250, function(){
        });
    };

    $("#overSlide3").mouseout(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideUp(250, function(){
        });
    };

 $("#overSlide4").mouseover(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideDown(250, function(){
        });
    };

    $("#overSlide4").mouseout(function(){
        $("#menuDiv").slideUp(250, function(){
        });
    };

});
```

This might be a little buggy, jquery is wierd sometimes doesn't work as expected.  If this doesn't work for you, there are other ways, this was just the simplest way compared to what you already had.   Just let me know and I will help more.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I've actually found a better way. My answer is in my comment's post since I can't answer my own questions earlier yet.